# Django form value not changing in views

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to set the value of a `foreignKey` in the `views.py` file, but it does not change.

models.py

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    sht = models.ForeignKey(Sheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```py
def addItem(request, slug):
    sheet = Sheet.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = forms.AddItem()

    if request.user == sheet.author:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = forms.AddItem(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=False)
                form.sht = Sheet.objects.get(slug=slug) # This is where it should change
                form.save()

                return redirect('sheets:detail', slug=slug)
        else:
            form = forms.AddItem()
            form.sht = Sheet.objects.get(slug=slug)
        return render(request, 'sheets/addItem.html', { 'form': form, 'slug': slug })
    else:
        return redirect('sheets:list')
```

After the form is saved, after looking in the admin console, the `sht` never changes and is still equal to `blank`. I have confirmed that there is a `Sheet` object when the views.py runs `Sheet.objects.get(slug=slug)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling form.save() on a model form it will always return a model instance.
What you wanna do here is set a relationship on that instance.

You might think you are modifying one and the same thing, but you are calling `.save()` again on your form which will result in creating a new instance disregarding what you've done before.

This might solve your problem:

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.sht = Sheet.objects.get(slug=slug)
    instance.save()
    return redirect('sheets:detail', slug=slug)
```